# uninitialized constant of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Hi i am trying to use cancan but I have very irritating error, namely: uninitialized constant Edition

for controller :

```
class EditionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user! #devise
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
  end
end
```

with this route:

```
get "editions/index"
```

and such abilities:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.has_role? "admin"
  can :manage, Edition
  cannot :commission
else
  can :read, :commission
end
```

And additional question, how i can create cancan ability for singular(name) controller ?
for example PhotoController

Comment: Do you have an ActiveRecord model named `Edition`?

Comment: Yes i was it, I changed load_and_authorize_resource to authorize_resource :class => false . This convention over configuration can be very deceiving . And of course :editions instead of Edition

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are using a custom class.

CanCan tries to singularize the controller class name to match the model class name and that sometimes isn't what we expect:

> ...
>
> If the model class is namespaced differently than the controller you will need to specify the :class option.

source: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

In my case, I had a class with no model, so I just added ":class => false" at the end of the command:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :class => false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `load_and_authorize_resource` defined in the `ApplicationController` and want to override it only for this controller:

```
class EditionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @editions = Edition.accessible_by(current_ability).order(:date)
  end
end
```